# Cross-built rpm; rpm install on target says: "intended for a different operating system"

Tags: operating-system, installation, cross-platform, rpm

Like the title says:

I *cross-built* an rpm (build system=x86_64; target=rpi). When I try to install it, with rpm, on the target, I get the message `intended for a different operating system`. I can successfully install it using the switch *--ignoreos*. But I'd much rather install it *normally* - as in: `rpm -ivh <my.rpm>`. (I am guessing there might be something in the build process to set this)

I believe (but am not sure) that the file `/usr/lib/os-release`, on either or both systems, has something to do with this. But I don't know which to change, and to what. Or perhaps it is something else.

Could someone explain how this works, and maybe how to fix this?

FWIW: the build system runs Fedora 23 (f23); the target system runs *pignus-23*, which is simply a build of f23 for the rpi 1 (hence an os name difference).

Answer (score 1):

Compare the OS reported by "rpm --showrc" and by "rpm -qp --qf'%{OS}\n' *.rpm".

You may be able to override the os reported by uname(2) using search(8) and/or personality(2 (but I'm not seeing any obvious way to generally change the os string).

You can also change the os (and arch) compatibility tables to include whatever string is being reported. If you are truly going to stick with an os designation that is not "linux", then you ought to apply a patch to lib/rpmrc.c in rpm somehow.

Comment: On my computer the command that works is: `rpm -qp --qf '%{OS}\n' *.rpm` (with a space after `--qf`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the target OS. Normally, the target can be set using the [`--target`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpmbuild) option, but since you don't need to change the CPU or architecture, you can just define the `_target_os` macro directly:

```sh
rpmbuild --define "_target_os ${TARGET_OS}" [...]
```

For example:

```sh
rpmbuild --define "_target_os linux" [...]
```